# how to match an integer with varchar containing digits separated by commas in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

I am facing a strange scenario where I need to match an integer with varchar containing digits separated by commas in oracle

Example:

**Table t1:**

```
id integer
key integer
```

Table t2

```
id integer,
keys varchar2
```

**T1 values are:**

```
1,111
2,201
3,301
```

**T2 values are:**

```
1, "111,301"
2, "111,201"
3, "201,301"
```

PROBLEM: Is there any way I can match or regular_expression match with key of T1 with keys of T2?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column.

Comment: @kattashri a_horse_with_no_name have a point there. You must alter your database as soon as possible. Split field "keys" and put each key in a separate record (into field with integer type). You will avoid many problems in times to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a regular join without regex for this:

```
select *
  from t1
       inner join t2
               on ','||t2.keys||',' like '%,'||to_char(t1.key)||',%';
```

eg:

```
SQL> create table t1(id, key)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 111 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 201 from dual union all
  5  select 3, 301 from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table t2(id, keys)
  2  as
  3  select 1, '111,301' from dual union all
  4  select 2, '111,201' from dual union all
  5  select 3, '201,301' from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select *
  2    from t1
  3         inner join t2
  4                 on ','||t2.keys||',' like '%,'||to_char(t1.key)||',%';

        ID        KEY         ID KEYS
---------- ---------- ---------- -------
         1        111          1 111,301
         1        111          2 111,201
         2        201          2 111,201
         2        201          3 201,301
         3        301          1 111,301
         3        301          3 201,301

6 rows selected.
```

It's not regex, just concatenation. For example lets say we wanted to compare

```
KEY    KEYS
111    111,301
```

we could say

```
where keys like '%'||key||'%'
```

i.e. expanded, this is

```
where '111,301' like '%111%'
```

which matches fine. But I added some commas there too. ie I did this:

```
where ',111,301,' like '%,111,%'
```

Why? imagine instead you had this data:

```
KEY    KEYS
111    1111,301
```

If we did the simple join:

```
where '1111,301' like '%111%'
```

it would incorrectly match. By injecting leading and trailing commas on both sides:

```
where ',1111,301,' like '%,111,%'
```

is no longer erroneously matches, as `,1111,` isn't like `,111,`.

Comment: Thnks u so much DazzaL. It perfectly worked out. But can you explain in detail or share some links about the regular expression matching in your query

Comment: @kattashri some detail added for you on why I injected  commas. it's not regex, just a simple `LIKE` join

Comment: And what about zero-padded numbers in nicely-looking width-aligned strings in T2 such as `4, "004,401"` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff the poster has not indicated that they are padding the numbers at all. if they are then the join would have to change to accomodate this (depending on the length they pad to)

Comment: I think it is also possible to add instr function in the above query?

Comment: @kattashri yes, i.e. `on instr(','||t2.keys||',', ','||to_char(t1.key)||',') > 0`